# Detener el ciclo de foreach C#

Tags: c#, linq

Lo que estoy haciendo es una consulta linq por el cual mando a obtener los valores que fueron ingresador en el login hasta ahora el obtiene los valores que se le especifican pero el recorre todas las filas y guarda enlas variables globales el ultimo registro que se ingreso 
ejemplo si ingreso con el usuario juan es el 1ero de la fila entonces el sigue recorriendo y solo detecta el ultimo registro en este caso fue pedro

Como hago para detener si ya encontro los datos especifados

```
 private void ActualizarLista()
    {

        List<Usuario_E> listausuario;
        Usuario_L listam = new Usuario_L();
        List<Rol_E> roles = new List<Rol_E>();
        roles = new Roles_L().ListarRoles();
        listausuario = listam.ListarUsuario();

        var lista = (from usuario in listausuario
                     join r in roles
                     on usuario.IdRol equals r.IdRol
                     select new
                     {
                         Nombre = usuario.Nombres,
                         Apellidos = usuario.Apellidos,
                         Codigo = r.Codigo
                     });

        foreach (var obtener in lista)
        {

                //Guardar los valores en las variables globales 
                Global.Nombre = obtener.Nombre;
                Global.Apellido = obtener.Apellidos;
                Global.CodigoRol = obtener.Codigo;



        }
    }
```

Comment: No es muy clara tu pregunta amigo, te recomendaría que trates de especificarla o describirlo un poco mejor para poder brindarte ayuda. Saludos

Comment: El comando break suele ser el usado para salir de las estructuras de control. Haz la comparación y, si es verdadera, usa `break`

Comment: @EdgarVazquez Estoy realizando un login porque cual ingreso los datos usuario y contra, entonces cree el metodo ACTUALIZARLISTA() para obtener los datos de ese usuario de ahi todo correcto, lo que necesito es que busque especificamente los datos del usuario que fue ingresado

Comment: Como estas validando si se encontraron los datos que son ?

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema esta en la consulta linq.

La misma nunca esta buscando un usuario en particular, si no que los esta trayendo todos.

Tu funcion deberia recibir el id del usuario que queres, y luego en la consulta linq solamente traer ese:

```
private void ActualizarLista(int IdUsuario)
{

    List<Usuario_E> listausuario;
    Usuario_L listam = new Usuario_L();
    List<Rol_E> roles = new List<Rol_E>();
    roles = new Roles_L().ListarRoles();
    listausuario = listam.ListarUsuario();

    var lista = (from usuario in listausuario
                 join r in roles
                 on usuario.IdRol equals r.IdRol
                where usuario.IdUsuario = IdUsuario
                 select new
                 {
                     Nombre = usuario.Nombres,
                     Apellidos = usuario.Apellidos,
                     Codigo = r.Codigo
                 });
    //Guardar los valores en las variables globales 
    Global.Nombre = lista.Nombre;
    Global.Apellido = lista.Apellidos;
    Global.CodigoRol = lista.Codigo;
}
```

Fijate que agregue un where, para despues no tener que recorrer toda la lista.

Si sin embargo, quisieras recorrer toda tu lista, el problema es que tu for solamente guarda en las variable el ultimo.

Tendrias que hacer algo asi para evitar eso (siempre suponiendo que recibis el id del usuario)

```
foreach (var obtener in lista)
{
    if (obtener.IdUsuario = IdUsuario)
    {              
        //Guardar los valores en las variables globales 
        Global.Nombre = obtener.Nombre;
        Global.Apellido = obtener.Apellidos;
        Global.CodigoRol = obtener.Codigo;
    }
}
```